# Incorrect implementation of C++ Selection sort. Any advise

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have tried to implement selection sort here. Please let me know what is wrong here and if there is anything wrong with the implementation of selection sort

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void selectionsort(int arr, int size)
{
int temp = 0;
int min = 0;
int i, j, k;

for (i = 0; i<size-1;i++)
{
    min = arr[i];
    for(j = i+1; j<size; j++)
    {
        if(arr[j] <  min)
        {
            temp = min; 
            min = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }

        else if (arr[j] >= min)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}    

for (k = 0; k <size; k++)
{
    cout<<arr[k];
}
}

int main()
{
int arr1[] = {5, 3, 4, 2, 1};
int size = sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]);
selectionsort(arr1, size);

return 0;
}
```

Please let me know what is wrong here and if there is anything wrong with the implementation of selection sort.

Comment: The parameter type should be `int* arr`.

Comment: `void selectionsort(int arr[] , int size)`

Comment: Or, of course, there's `void selectionsort(std::vector<int> arr)`, and you can keep the data and its size nice and tidy in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem in your code swapping does not work as intended in selection sort.
I would suggest to store index in min variable and swap values outside of second loop.

```
    min = i;
    for (j = i + 1; j<size; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] < arr[min])
        {
            min = j;
        } 
    }
    temp = arr[min];
    arr[min] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = temp;
```

And don't forget to change parameter type as it is commented already